# Is there an App that will fix this?

Tags: cipher

My friend bought a new keyboard the other day was trying it out for the first time while I was talking to him on the phone.
He told me, "OMG, I got a lemon! this thing doesn't work!"
I said "Why, what's the problem?"
Then he started laughing and sent me the following in the body of an email:

> o [iy ,u gomhrtd pm yjr etpmh lrud@

What was the problem?

**50 imaginary Bonus Points** - *Is* there an app that will fix this?

Comment: Why imaginary? Bounty! :P

Comment: While perfectly solvable anyway, this puzzle's exact details can vary (even quite a lot) depending on which country you are in.

Comment: @Bass Before submitting this, I actually did some research, and saw that while [many variations exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout), the one I used for this puzzle is ["By far the most widespread layout in use, and the only one that is not confined to a particular geographical area."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#QWERTY).

Comment: @Chowzen From the linked puzzle, you can work out that the latter quoted clause is false.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Although the friend in the linked puzzle uses the Dvorak system, his physical keyboard is still a QWERTY one, as it is still ["The Most Preferred Keyboard"](https://www.scienceabc.com/innovation/qwerty-keyboard-over-the-years-why-is-it-the-most-preferred-typing-tool.html)

Comment: @Chowzen It's not the only one that is not confined to a particular geographical area.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The message in the e-mail is

> i put my fingers on the wrong keys!

Obtained by

> Typing the key on a qwerty keyboard that is to the left of the character in the e-mail.

Comment: I knew it would be pretty easy to solve, but *3 minutes!* C'mon, man! :)

Answer (score 9):

## $0 + 50i$

There are several apps that can remap the keyboard, like [AutoHotKey](https://superuser.com/a/1055167/120610) and [KLM](http://www.klm32.com/).

Microsoft even offers an official [Keyboard Layout Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339) app if you want to define your own custom layout, although I think it does not support Windows 10.

Even without any apps, operating systems natively support changing keyboard layouts for different regions or alternate layouts, like Dvorak, for example. In Windows 10, you can add layouts in *Region and language settings*. Click the language, then options to see keyboard layouts.

Comment: The Unicorn Points are yours! I was actually thinking more along the lines of if you put your fingers on the wrong keys the dictionary/auto-correct could fix it for you. I type in low lighting situations often at home and often myself "fpomh yjsy." (doing that) :)

Comment: @Chowzen, keyboards have little bumps on the f and k keys, the "home keys", so that you can orient yourself even in the dark.

Comment: @dan-gph I think you mean f and j. If yours are on f and k then that could certainly lead to (at least half of) the issues above...

Comment: @bobajob, ha ha, yes, that was weird. I should have used the bumps to to type them.

Comment: You'll find this funny, @dan-gph [The inspiration for my question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/63326/my-friend-sent-me-a-photo-of-his-keyboard-but-theres-something-i-cant-figure/63333#comment192701_63333)

Answer (score 2):

50 imaginary Bonus Points

I haven't found an app yet, but you could

> Shift your keyboard to the right and try not to look down as you type.

Answer (score 2):

The email is:

> i put my fingers on the wrong keys!

How did this happen?

> The keyboard's groove lines are not on the `F` and `J` keys, as normal, but are on the `G` and `K`, causing your friend to shift his key presses one key off to the right.

An app to fix it?

The simplest solution would be to

> ignore the groove lines, which he can do because he typed your email address correctly

If your friend cannot do that, he can

> replace the G, K, F and J keys with another keyboard- maybe his old one?

Comment: I think you meant to go in the other direction, to G/K

Comment: Home row is not the only way to type. I find the grooves on the F and J keys annoying and unnecessary because I don't use home row.